# PL/SQL assigning query results to a CLOB

Tags: oracle, excel, plsql

I have a problem, I am creating an CLOB variable with the contents of a query in oracle to email to users, the problem is that it does email as .csv but with no contents. I can not find the problems:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE trackekr(cursor1 IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
    v_connection  UTL_SMTP.connection;
    v_clob        CLOB := EMPTY_CLOB();
    v_len         INTEGER;
    v_index       INTEGER;
 c_mime_boundary CONSTANT VARCHAR2(256) := 'the boundary can be almost anything';

    rec           NUMBER(10, 0) := 0;
    d_id          NUMBER(10, 0) := 0;
    customer      VARCHAR2(20);
    wife          VARCHAR2(20);
    date_rec      DATE;
    special_h     VARCHAR2(20);
    g_amount      NUMBER(10, 0) := 0;
    credit_amount NUMBER(10, 0) := 0;
    a_number      VARCHAR2(20);
    a__name       VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
    OPEN cursor1 FOR
        SELECT rec,
               d_id,
               customer,
               wife,
               date_rec,
               special h,
               g_amount
          FROM  (your query here);

    WHILE cursor1%NOTFOUND
    LOOP
        FETCH cursor1
              INTO rec,
                   d_id,
                   customer,
                   wife,
                   date_rec,
                   special_h,
                   g_amount,
                   credit_amount,
                   a_number,
                   a__name;

        v_clob :=
               v_clob
            || rec
            || ','
            || d_id
            || ','
            || customer
            || ','
            || wife
            || ','
            || date_rec
            || ','
            || special_h
            || ','
            || g_amount
            || ','
            || credit_amount
            || ','
            || a_number
            || ','
            || a__name
            || UTL_TCP.crlf;
    END LOOP;

    -- UTL

    v_connection := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(mailhost, 25);  
    SMTP server name or ip address
    UTL_SMTP.helo(v_connection, mail.exchange.mydomain.com);
    UTL_SMTP.mail(v_connection, 'mylogin.Exchange.mydomain.com');
    UTL_SMTP.rcpt(v_connection, 'mylogin.Exchange.mydomain.com'); 
    UTL_SMTP.open_data(v_connection);

    UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection, 'From: ' || 'mylogin.Exchange.mydomain.com' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection, 'To: ' || 'mylogin.Exchange.mydomain.com' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection, 'Subject: test subject' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.crlf);

    UTL_SMTP.write_data(
        v_connection,
        'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' || c_mime_boundary || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf
    );
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection, UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(
        v_connection,
        'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.' || UTL_TCP.crlf
    );

    UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection, '--' || c_mime_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection, 'Content-Type: text/plain' || UTL_TCP.crlf);

    -- Set up attachment header
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(
        v_connection,
        'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || 'FIRSTFILE.csv' || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf
    );
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection, UTL_TCP.crlf);

    -- Write attachment contents

    v_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength(v_clob);
    v_index := 1;

    WHILE v_index <= v_len
    LOOP
        UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection, DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(v_clob, 32000, v_index));
        v_index := v_index + 32000;
    END LOOP;

    -- End attachment
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection, UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection, '--' || c_mime_boundary || '--' || UTL_TCP.crlf);

    UTL_SMTP.close_data(v_connection);
    UTL_SMTP.quit(v_connection);
END;
```

As I said, it emails a .csv file but empty.

Comment: How many rows do you get as output of cursor1?

Comment: Usually, it's a good idea to use UTL_SMTP.write_raw_data and encode to base64 for attachements. Hope this example (http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_email_attachment.htm) could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note this part in your code:

```
WHILE cursor1%NOTFOUND
```

Your loop will never be executed for non-empty dataset. Use this instead:

```
WHILE cursor1%FOUND
```

Or even better use implicit cursor:

```
FOR cursor1 in
        (SELECT rec,
               d_id,
               customer,
               wife,
               date_rec,
               special_h,
               g_amount,
               credit_amount,
               a_number,
               a__name
          FROM  (your query here))
LOOP
v_clob :=
               v_clob
            || cursor1.rec
            || ','
            || cursor1.d_id
            || ','
            || cursor1.customer
            || ','
            || cursor1.wife
            || ','
            || cursor1.date_rec
            || ','
            || cursor1.special_h
            || ','
            || cursor1.g_amount
            || ','
            || cursor1.credit_amount
            || ','
            || cursor1.a_number
            || ','
            || cursor1.a__name
            || UTL_TCP.crlf;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Just a question, where the while condition should be set?

Comment: If it's about your code then the first "while" condition should be replaced. If it's regarding implicit cursor example then there is no "while". In implicit cursors "for" clause is used instead. You can find more information on it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1155).

Comment: I meant in your code since there is no "while" condition does in it go into an infinite loop?

Comment: I am sorry, my bad please excuse my ignorance, I am trying now but it is taking time, that's why I was thinking that it went into infinite loop.

Comment: It keeps on running, but no results produced, is it maybe running into an infinite loop?

Comment: Try this: SELECT 'rec',
               'd_id',
               'customer',
               'wife',
               'date_rec',
               'special_h',
               'g_amount',
               'credit_amount',
               'a_number',
               'a__name',
          FROM  dual
union all
SELECT rec,
               d_id,
               customer,
               wife,
               date_rec,
               special_h,
               g_amount,
               credit_amount,
               a_number,
               a__name
          FROM  (your query here)

Comment: Thank you, It worked great, now I have another problem, since my data comes with comma like 'Mr Josehp Cares, A' the extra coma makes excel create an extra column and the headers are off, is there a way to include formatting? actually the best thing for me is if I instead of creating a .csv creating a .xls file with full formatting.  Is this possible?

Comment: You can use TAB as column separator. Also you can enclose each column value in quotes like that: "Mr Josehp Cares, A". When importing into excel everything should be fine with some tuning of import parameters. Just play around. Concerning export to excel .xls files there are several ways but surely it is much more complicated matter and it is far beyond subject of your initial question. I suggest you to mark this question as answered and search this site for 'oracle to .xls export' because I am pretty sure that have seen something not long ago.

Answer (score 0):

The example below, write the query to clob and then to blob to put in a file

You just need to use the first step, until the line 87

SELECT dbms_lob.getlength(l_clob) INTO len FROM dual;

```
DECLARE
  l_output      utl_file.file_type;
  c1            INTEGER DEFAULT dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  l_columnvalue VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_status      INTEGER;
  l_colcnt      NUMBER := 0;
  l_separator   VARCHAR2(30);
  l_desctbl     dbms_sql.desc_tab;
  l_flag        NUMBER;
  l_dir         VARCHAR2(50);
  l_arq         VARCHAR2(100);
  l_clob        CLOB;
  l_query       VARCHAR2(50);
  vstart        NUMBER := 1;
  bytelen       NUMBER := 32000;
  len           NUMBER;
  my_vr         RAW(32000);
  x             NUMBER;
  dest_offset   INTEGER;
  src_offset    INTEGER;
  blob_csid     NUMBER;
  lang_context  INTEGER;
  blb           BLOB;
  warning       INTEGER;
BEGIN
  l_query := 'select * from safx07_v  where rownum <=100';

  SELECT 'safx07' || to_char(SYSDATE, 'DDMMYY_HH24MISS') || '.txt'
    INTO l_arq
    FROM dual;

  l_dir := 'ORACLE_EXP';

  l_output := utl_file.fopen(l_dir, l_arq, 'wb');
  --l_output := utl_file.fopen('ORACLE_EXP', 'filename.txt', 'wb', 32760);
  --l_separator := separator;

  IF l_separator = '' OR l_separator IS NULL THEN
    l_separator := chr(9);
  END IF;

  dbms_sql.parse(c1, l_query, dbms_sql.native);
  dbms_sql.describe_columns(c1, l_colcnt, l_desctbl);

  dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_clob, TRUE,DBMS_LOB.call);

  /*  

  FOR cr IN (l_query) LOOP

    dbms_lob.writeappend(l_clob, length(cr.txt), cr.txt);

  END LOOP;*/

  FOR i IN 1 .. l_colcnt LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(l_desctbl(i).col_name || l_separator);
    dbms_output.put_line(length(l_desctbl(i).col_name || l_separator));
    /*    utl_file.put(l_output, l_desctbl(i).col_name || l_separator);
    dbms_sql.define_column(c1, i, l_columnvalue, 4000);*/

    dbms_lob.writeappend(l_clob,
                         length(l_desctbl(i).col_name || l_separator),
                         l_desctbl(i).col_name || l_separator);
    dbms_sql.define_column(c1, i, l_columnvalue, 4000);

  END LOOP;

  --utl_file.new_line(l_output);

  l_status := dbms_sql.execute(c1);

  dbms_lob.writeappend(l_clob, length(chr(10)), chr(10));

  WHILE (dbms_sql.fetch_rows(c1) > 0) LOOP
    FOR i IN 1 .. l_colcnt LOOP
      /*      dbms_sql.column_value(c1, i, l_columnvalue);
      utl_file.put(l_output, l_columnvalue || l_separator);*/
      dbms_sql.column_value(c1, i, l_columnvalue);
      dbms_lob.writeappend(l_clob, length(l_columnvalue || l_separator),
                           l_columnvalue || l_separator);
    END LOOP;
    dbms_lob.writeappend(l_clob, length(chr(10)), chr(10));
  END LOOP;

  --utl_file.fclose(l_output);

  SELECT dbms_lob.getlength(l_clob) INTO len FROM dual;

  dbms_lob.createtemporary(blb, FALSE);
  dest_offset  := 1;
  src_offset   := 1;
  lang_context := 0;

  -- convert to a BLOB here:
  dbms_lob.converttoblob(blb, l_clob, dbms_lob.getlength(l_clob),
                         dest_offset, src_offset, 0, lang_context, warning);

  -- if small enough for a single write
  IF len < 32760 THEN
    utl_file.put_raw(l_output, blb);
    utl_file.fflush(l_output);
  ELSE
    -- write in pieces
    vstart := 1;
    WHILE vstart < len AND bytelen > 0 LOOP
      dbms_lob.read(blb, bytelen, vstart, my_vr);

      utl_file.put_raw(l_output, my_vr);
      utl_file.fflush(l_output);

      -- set the start position for the next cut
      vstart := vstart + bytelen;

      -- set the end position if less than 32000 bytes
      x := x - bytelen;
      IF x < 32000 THEN
        bytelen := x;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
  dbms_sql.close_cursor(c1);
  utl_file.fclose(l_output);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_sql.close_cursor(c1);
    utl_file.fclose(l_output);
    RAISE;
END;
```